# How to detect if an arrow is in the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For some reason when I do:

```
/kill @e[type=Arrow] {inGround:1b}
```

It kills all arrows.

The correct output should be it only killing arrows that are in the ground. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/kill` command syntax:

```
/kill <target>
```

It does not support NBT input. You will instead have to label the target based on their data first, such as with `/scoreboard`, and then target them based on the label after.

#### 1.9

No objective necessary.

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Arrow,tag=!kill] add kill {inGround:1b}
/kill @e[type=Arrow,tag=kill]
```

#### 1.8

Objective required.

```
/scoreboard objectives add kill dummy
```

Then for detection:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow] kill 1 {inGround:1b}
/kill @e[type=Arrow,score_kill_min=1]
```

Comment: Okay, yes, that explains a bunch of problems I've had with the kill command. It also taught me a new thing about scoreboards I should have already known. This worked, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this is not going to work in 1.8 is it? Because "tag" was added in 1.9. I should of mentioned Is there a way to do this in 1.8?

Comment: @Pingyoping Yes, modified my post to include it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for bedrock edition?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in which version it became possible, but for anyone who is interested, the modern answer to this is:

```
/kill @e[type=arrow,nbt={inGround:1b}]
```

(Be warned that nbt selectors are said to be *relatively* expensive though.)